# Pinterest Share HTML Link error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pinterest

I am having an issue with my 'Share to Pinterest' link. I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfezypfj/) if it helps.

Basically the `url` portion isn't being carried into my new pop up window :'-(

Here's my Javascript too:

```
$('.share.pinterest').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this),
            url = target.data('url') || "";

        var width  = 575,
            height = 400,
            left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
            top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
            gplus    = 'https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+ url + '',
            opts   = 'status=1' +
                     ',width='  + width  +
                     ',height=' + height +
                     ',top='    + top    +
                     ',left='   + left;


        window.open(gplus, 'Pinterest', opts);

    });
```

Many thanks for any help & guidance with this issue.

Comment: In your fiddle you don't have a data attribute on the .share.pinterest tag and in your code you are trying to get the url as a data parameter target.data('url') || "". SO no data tag no url value :)

Comment: Can you show me what I need to do in my JSFiddle to amend this? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php if(function_exists('the_post_thumbnail')) echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>&description=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?> - <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" id="pinterest" target="_blank">Pinterest Pin It</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Encode your `url` parameter using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
gplus = 'https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='
        + encodeURIComponent(url)
```

### Edit:

It's because pinterest is redirecting your url to this:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/join/?next=/pin/create/button/
```

During this redirect that is done by pinterest, it encodes the url for you and changes the static url you entered to a querystring version.  So you may want to submit the request like this instead:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/join/?next=/pin/create/button/&url=
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you can change it. Pinterest does this redirect to encode everything after `/button/`, see here: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=

Comment: Make sure you're structuring the url correctly, because you can't have a querystring `?` in another querystring `?`, maybe you want to use `&url=` instead of `?url=` ?

Comment: Can you possibly try this in jsfiddle as any attempts I have made have failed :-(

Comment: I did and this is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/hfezypfj/5/ It's not working as I was hoping it would

Comment: It's working, your url value is empty, what do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. I have `http://www.google.com` as my value in `url`.

Comment: You don't have any value under `url`, you have a value under `href`. Do this then: `url = target.attr('href') || "";` or add a `data-url` attribute to your `<a>` element.

Comment: This looks closer to it: http://jsfiddle.net/hfezypfj/3/ but then how would I add a description?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not pinterest. Check pinterest docs to see how you add a description.  I'm guessing you just pass another querystring value.

Comment: If this answer answers your question, please accept it as best answer.  If you have other questions, please ask them separately because your question about the description would be out of the scope of this question.